# What does liquid-vapor coexistence look like microscopically?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Suppose I have a prepared a fluid at conditions where liquid and vapor coexist at a common temperature. What does the interface between the two phases look like microscopically? If I scan an imaginary microscope from the liquid to the vapor, should I expect to see a gradual transition from higher density to lower density? Or should I expect the interface to be patchy, with blobs of liquid suspended in the vapor?

If I prepare the system either at its critical point or right on the saturation dome (as opposed to under the saturation dome), do I expect a different answer?

Or is this a question that can't be reasoned about thermodynamically and requires a detailed accounting of the molecular/atomic interactions?

Answer (score 0):

If you had teeny teeny eyes, you might see this:

A ragged interface between the air (filled with speeding water molecules) and liquid (water molecules barely hanging on to one another, densely packed). right at the interface, water molecules are breaking free and zooming off into the air and at the same time, water molecules in the air come speeding back into the interface, slam into it, and stick.

At equilibrium conditions, the rates of water evaporation into the air and condensation back to the liquid state are equal.